# htaccess problem

Tags: .htaccess

i have to write htaccess for mysite. actually we have two domains. '.com and .in' . for example i opened '.com' site it will actomatically access files from '.in' domain. there is no files in .com site. how to write .htaccess for this.

thanks.

Comment: actomatically access is nothing you have to redirect from .com domain to .in domain with the request uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the web server, use the configuration to archieve this. In case of apache2, it would just require a server alias in the virtual host. Otherwise, use redirects or url rewriting.

If you cannot use them either (because you are on a limited virtual environment, f.e.), place an index.html in your .com directory, configure it to redirect via meta-refresh tag. Place the following line in the header section of your index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://yourinsite.in/">
```

Then use the DirectoryIndex directive on a .htaccess file to automatically load it as default index page:

DirectoryIndex index.html

This brings up the index.html when the user browses yoursite.com/ and lead her to yourinsite.in automatically.

Comment: ok thanks for your reply. but i have a small doubt. plz tell me i am in .com site i am accessing files from .in. still i have to display .com domain in url. is it possible?

Comment: yes, again via the server configuration: use the rewrite engine (apache, iis has similar). And its possible without changing the config as well: replace the .com dir with a symlink (linux?) which points to the .in dir. You may need administrative rights and a shell access in order to do this. .htaccess would than require the 'FollowSymlinks' option.

Comment: It would help to know, if it needs to be a solution **without** having access to the server config? Changing the config would be the best and easiest solution. Other options will be more hacky.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the server config? Judging by your comment above what you actually want is to setup a [server alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#serveralias), where the .com and .in sites are the same? This will make the .com site load the .in or vice versa.

Comment: actually there is no files in .com.if i open www.example.com it will access files from www.example.in. is it possible?

Comment: Yes - as I said you need to use a server alias: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#serveralias

Comment: yes as you said my website administrator connected when i opened '.com' it is redirecting to '.in'. upto here working fine. but in the url i have to display '.com'.

Comment: for example i am opening 'www.test.com/usa/' it is redirecting to 'www.test.in/usa' . upto here fine. but i have to display 'www.test.com/usa/' in the url when i am opening webpage from '.com'

Comment: A server alias does not redirect you, it simply means treat the .com as if it were the .in. Something else in your setup must be redirecting.

Comment: example like this please click here:http://example.net/ or http://example.com/        displaying same web page

Comment: i am asking about Domain masking lets you protect the address of a particular site, while still allowing customers to access the content. Here's how it works:

First, you register a domain name, say, domain1.com. This is only an address, though; domain1.com is not going to have its own web site. You use this address to display the content of another web site, say, forwarded-to.com.

So your visitors type in www.domain1.com and see the display from the forwarded-to.com web site. But they do not see the forwarded-to.com address.

Comment: Server Aliases do exactly this. Maybe try seeking experts in your native language as you aren't really understanding what I am saying.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution you could use if you don't have server access it use a domain frame cloak, which will keep the .com URL in the address bar but load the .in site inside a frame, put this code in index.html on the .com site, fill in what toy need to.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TITLE OF THE SITE</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="Description" content="Description of the site"
  </head>  
    <frameset rows="100%,*">

    <frame frameborder="0" src="http://domain.in" scrolling="auto">
    <noframes>
      <body>
          <p><b>Welcome on our site. Your browser do not support frames.</b></p>
          <p><a href="http://domain.in">Click here to go to the page.</a></p>
      </body>
    </noframes>
  </frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: ok fine. but this is not the correct solution to my problem. www.test.in?query=1&string=2; it will display in '.com' site as www.test.com?query=1&string=2;